# Thread terminates when user intervention required in Word OLE

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ole

We have a thread which when created, launches a Word OLE instance as follows:

```
MSWord:=CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
MSWord.Visible:=FALSE;
document:=MSWord.Documents.Open(Fdocfile);
thisActiveDocument:=MSWord.ActiveDocument;
thisActiveDocument.Save;
document.Close;
MSWord.Quit(FALSE);
```

We execute this in a thread so that we can also have a progress bar to inform the user that something is going on behind the scenes. (see [Delphi OLE Automation freezing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220440/delphi-ole-automation-freezing-gui))

We now have a problem however, where if the document being opened requires user intervention, a password protected document for example, the thread terminates as soon as the user enters the password, and the rest of the code in the thread Execute does not run.

Comment: According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx there are some options for including the password with the 'open' method.  If all else fails, perhaps you could prompt your user for a password, in your program.  Don't leave it up to Word.  There is a possibility that the 'Open' call returned, and then the rest of your code executed, prior to the user even entering their password.

Comment: How did you initialize COM?